# print variable in new line

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I am listing for example :

```
test <- unique(df$sed)

"A"
"B"
"C"
```

In order to refer to knitr to the above variable, I am using:

`r test` .

But, the problem is that it prints : `A,B,C`

I want to print:

```
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the chunk option `comment=""`, e.g.,

````
```{r comment=""}
cat(test, sep = "\n")  
```
````

Comment: `tidy=FALSE` is the default, so you don't need to set it; the key here is `comment=""`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
cat(paste(test,collapse = "\n"))
```

Comment: Thanks, but it needs `{r tidy=FALSE, comment=""}..`